# Jasmine Spies.and.stub method

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I've been reading through the Jasmine documentation and I've been struggling to understand what the Spies `.and.stub` method actually does. English is not my native language, so I don't even know what the word "stub" actually means, and there is no translation for it in my language.

In the documentation it says:

> When a calling strategy is used for a spy, the original stubbing behavior can be returned at any time with and.stub.

```
describe("A spy", function() {  

var foo, bar = null;

  beforeEach(function() {
    foo = {
      setBar: function(value) {
        bar = value;
      }
    };

    spyOn(foo, 'setBar').and.callThrough();
  });

  it("can call through and then stub in the same spec", function() {
    foo.setBar(123);
    expect(bar).toEqual(123);

    foo.setBar.and.stub();
    bar = null;

    foo.setBar(123);
    expect(bar).toBe(null);
  });
});
```

What does `and.stub` actually do and how is it useful?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

For the term, you can look at wikipedia : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_stub

In a nutshell it's a "fake" object that you can control that replaces a "real" object in your code.

For the function, what I understand is that `and.stub()` removes the effect of `and.callThrough()` on a spy.

When you call `and.callThrough`, the spy acts as a proxy, calling the real function, but passing through a spy object allowing you to add tests like expectation.

When you call `and.stub`, or if you never call `and.callThrough`, the spy won't call the real function. It's really usefull when you don't want to test an object's behavior, but be sure that it was called. Helping you to keep your test truly unitary.

Comment: Thank you very much. The fact that the and.stub() removes the effect of and.callThrough() is what's missing on their documentation. It really explains everything.

Comment: How is it different then `spyOn(foo, 'setBar')` without `.and.callThrough()`?

Comment: agree with aycanadal. What is the use of `stub` as just `spyOn` seems to do the same thing. if I do `spyOn(foo,'setBar')`, `setBar`'s original implementation will not be called. In fact it seems, `stub` is same as calling `and.callFake(()=>{})`

Comment: jasmine mix the concept of spy and stub in it's syntax. A stub replace the implementation where a spy only act has a passthrough calling the actual implementation. To have a real spy you need to do `spyOn(..).and.callThrough()`. But you can re-enable the stub with `and.stub` after calling `callThrough`. Agreed it's mainly sugar ! `and.callFake` has a similar result.

Comment: @ManuChadha You may know this by now, but in case someone reading these comments is still confused: the point is to have a way to reset the spy to the default behavior after you have changed the behavior of the spy with `.and.callThrough()` or `and.callFake()`, etc, for a given test, for example if you do not want the call through or call fake behavior on other tests running with that spy.

Answer (score 18):

To complete the previous answer:

Indeed, it's not clear from the doc, but it's very clear in the source code:

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/4be20794827a63ca5295848c58ffc478624ee4dc/src/core/SpyStrategy.js

```
plan = function() {};
```

-> the called function is empty

```
this.callThrough = function() {
  plan = originalFn;
```

-> the called function is the original function

```
this.stub = function(fn) {
  plan = function() {};
```

-> the called function is empty (again)